# SonarLint - RedundantThrowsDeclarationCheck - false positive?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sonarqube, sonarlint

In the following code I get a warning from the `squid:RedundantThrowsDeclarationCheck` rule on the `Foo1Exception` (behind the `throws` keyword): `Remove the redundant '!unknownSymbol!' thrown exception declaration(s).`

*Foo.java:*

```
public class Foo {

    public static boolean bar(final String test) throws Foo1Exception, Foo2Exception {

        if (test.startsWith("a"))  {
            throw new Foo1Exception();
        } else if (test.startsWith("b")) {
            throw new Foo2Exception();
        } else if (test.startsWith("c")) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

Both exceptions are decrlared in seperate files:

*Foo1Exception.java:*

```
class Foo1Exception extends Exception {}
```

*Foo2Exception.java:*

```
class Foo2Exception extends Exception {}
```

I think this is a false positive, isn't it?
Also interesting: I don't get this message directly in SonarQube (web interface) only in the SonarLint plugin in IntelliJ IDEA.
Any Ideas?

I'm using: IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.2; SonarLint 2.3 (with working server binding); SonarQube 5.6; SonarQube Java Plugin 4.0; Java 8

Comment: Do you fetch rules from the same server (may be remote)? or just using default rule set??

Comment: How is your project setup exactly ? this seems like the type of the exception is not resolved and that's why an issue is (wrongly) raised. Is the source code of that exception in the same module ? can you share details about that ?

Comment: @SupunWijerathne, I have configured my remote server and clicked the "Update binding" button. And it's working. I'm using this since a few month without any problems and after changing rules on the server, clicking the "update" button I got the updated rules in SonarLint. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @benzonico, I don't know what you exactly want to know, sry. I'm working on a large multi module maven project and for my test which is described above I just created three new java classes (each in a seperate file) inside of **one** module. If I declare the two exception classes inside the `Foo` class as inner classes it works correctly. Only if they are in seperate Files the false positive messages are shown.

Comment: @CptS Have you fetched new rules using sonarqube plugin also? If two plugins are using different rule sets, obviously there can be mismatches between the issues they are generating. That's what I asked. :) In general SonarQube should report more issues -> All SonarLint issues + some others, since sonarlint runs independently on each file, while sonarqube is global.

Comment: @SupunWijerathne sry what do you mean with "fetched new rules"? Which "two plugins" do you mean? In SonarQube or in IntelliJ IDEA? I don't know how I can fetch new rules in SonarQube. I thought the rules are updated when I update the according plugin. In SonarLint I thought the rules are fetched by clicking on the "Update binding" button in the Server settings. In my opinion the two "sides" (IntelliJ IDEA and SonarQube itself) should use the same rules. Btw. some colleagues have the same problem, so it seems to be no installation mistake on my side. Any other ideas or tips what I can try?

Comment: @CptS Sorry I think I misunderstood your question with sonarqube server and sonarqube intellij plugin. Now I understood what the real issue is.  Have you configured SonarLint Project Settings Correctly?? File -> Settings -> Other Settings -> SonarLint Project Settings ??

Comment: @SupunWijerathne in the project settings I have enabled the binding to remote SonarQube server, the correct server and the correct project is selected. No "Analysis properties" are defined. I think this schould be right.

Comment: yes then it should be ok. At this point I can't go forward without replicating the issue myself. Anyway it is not a false positive. You can refer this detail about the issue. https://sonar.spring.io/rules/show/squid:RedundantThrowsDeclarationCheck?layout=false   This is coz you are throwing multiple exceptions. The problem is either mismatch between rules or execution problem in one of the sides. Is that soner-qube server link publicly available? And can you also please double-check whether exactly this issue is not there in the server.

Comment: The SonarQube server is not public because I'm working on a commercial closed source software, sry. I've checked again, the warning isn't there on the server for this case. The warning from this rule is there for other files where it is correct. But this file in which it isn't correct has no warnings at all. In SonarLint it shows me this message. Are there any SonarLint-logfiles, where I can find such execution problems?

Comment: Just for testing I currently changed the severity of the rule on the SonarQube server, then clicked the "update binding" button in the SonarLint server settings and then rerun the analysis and the severity is also changed in SonarLint. So I think this proves, that the rules are in sync and it must be a execution problem.

Comment: If it is the case SonarLint should be correct because you are throwing more than one exception in 'bar(final String test)' method. Don't know what's wrong with sonarQube (sonar-scanner) side. The only thing I can suggest now is, re-run the sonarqube scanner job (may be with jenkins) and find whether that issue is appearing there. Is this method a newly added/edited one?

Comment: I'll try a new server side analysis (bamboo) later. But I don't understand why you think, that SonarLint is OK. The given warning says that it is shown if "listed multiple times" (not applicable, this are two different exception classes) or "a subclass of another listed exception" (not applicable, both extends from `Exception`) or "a RuntimeException, or one of its descendants" (not applicable, again: both extends from `Exception`) or "completely unnecessary because the declared exception type cannot actually be thrown" (not applicable, both exceptions can be thrown in the method).

Comment: The analysis runs again but nothing changed. The SonarLint Warnings are still there but nothing in the web interface of SonarQube. I've missed you last question, sry. The class with the method and also the exception classes was newly added but by now it is already about 10 days ago and multiple sonarqube analyses are run (through bamboo ci).

Comment: I have also found other false positive warnings. For example some `squid:UnusedPrivateMethod` on private Methods which are actual used in a public method. IntelliJ IDEA checks this also and doesn't show a warning, what is correct. But I can't really reproduce this. For example if I remove the parameters on method signature and invocation the warning disappears. One of my colleagues tells me that this happens since last SonarLint update (I'm using Version 2.3). Can someone confirm that? Or does someone know what I can do if I think it's a bug in the SonarLint plugin for IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be fixed in [SonarLint 2.3.1](https://jira.sonarsource.com/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=11131&version=13382).